# Spring: Too many instances of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer causing Heap Space error

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

When I tried to go through Heap dump of my application. I found a single Huge instance of `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory`
which is retaining 75% of the heap.
What I found that, the big instance has a `LinkedList` named `embeddedValueResolvers` which hold 12k+ nodes of 
`org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

My application has few properties that needs to be loaded from `properties file`. I can see those properties are getting loaded in `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.
But what I am not getting is that why there are 12k+ instances of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Why are they not getting Garbage collected?

In my application I am using few Spring beans with `prototype scope`.

[VisualVM heap dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6RnV.jpg),
[Heap Dump Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLBeB.jpg)

Comment: There are multiple Spring Bugs reported related to this

# [Memory leak in serializable bean factory management](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7502)

# [DefaultListableBeanFactory memory leak spring version 3.0.5](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9842)

# [Memory leak in serializable bean factory management](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7502)

But I did not get clear idea or the root cause and the fix.